# Using CMIS, how to query/get documents for a user/user-id?

Tags: cmis

Using CMIS, how to query/get documents for a user/user-id? CMIS supports query by object id, does it support query by user-id? Sample query if any will help a lot.

Thanks,
Jawa

Answer (score 3):

Try:
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:createdBy = 'user-id'

Comment: Thanks Florian for your response. The problem that I try to address is with retrieving documents that a user has read access to, so query by cmis:createdBy will return only a subset for me. I am just trying to find a way out by querying the ACL of documents, but it will not be an optimal solution. Any further help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are logged in as the user, the query "SELECT * FROM cmis:document" gives you all the documents you are allowed to see. 
If you are logged in as a different user, you can't do that because that would be either a security hole or the result set would have to be incomplete and therefore worthless.